# Getting Drag/Move event on Applet window

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, japplet

I have an applet inside the browser window and a dialog on top of the applet.

My requirement is that I have to move the `JDialog` as and when the applet window is moved.

How can I track the event for component movement either at HTML or Java level?

Comment: By 'draggable' DYM the this type of [draggable applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/draggableApplet.html) or that the browser is being moved?

Comment: I meant when the browser is moved.

Comment: I suspect the only way to achieve what you require are to start a Swing `Timer` that checks the [`location on screen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) every `nn` milliseconds.